# Apt-get providing outdated version of youtube-dl

Tags: apt, youtube-dl

I just installed youtube-dl by doing `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`, but after typing `$ youtube-dl --version`, I get `2016.02.22`, which seems updated according to their github page, that says they are in version `2016.11.14.1`.

I suppose I could remove it and download the package from their github page, but I wonder why it didn't work using apt-get, and how could I fix it, since using apt seems the standard way of doing it.

Comment: You can add the webupd8 ppa to your system.  This provides a more up-to-date version of youtube-dl through the apt system.  https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Thanks for the link. How does webupd8 work? If I use that, does it mean that it will download and install all those programs? I guess not, but what does it mean that it updates them all? I guess I don't understand the relationship between ppas and the apt system. Could you please explain?

Comment: Not an expert, but apt looks in repositories to find updated versions of software that is installed on your system.  You can see the list of official repos your system is using by opening the "software and updates" program and looking at the Ubuntu Software tab.  PPAs are unofficial repositories not maintained by Ubuntu that contain additional and/or new versions of programs.  If you add a PPA to your system, it shows up under the Other Software tab.  Note that since these PPAs are unofficial there is some risk involved of getting sketchy software.  The link shows how to add the ppa.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them